# Using elements of an array with instanceof

Tags: java, arrays, instanceof

Is it possible to use instanceof with two elements in two different arrays?

For example: `if(arrayA[c] instanceof arrayB[c]){}`

I have tried the above code but get the following errors:

```
error: ']' expected: if(arrayA[c] instanceof arrayB[c]){}
                                                    ^
error: ';' expected: if(arrayA[c] instanceof arrayB[c]){}
                                                     ^
error: illegal start of expression: if(arrayA[c] instanceof arrayB[c]){}
                                                                     ^
```

Comment: does arrayB[c] contain a class ?

Comment: No, they contain objects of Token. I also have several classes that extend Token and want to make sure that the contents of the arrays are objects of the same class.

Comment: Then you are bound to get a compile time error. you need to ahve an object in the lhs of instanceOf and a class on the RHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Class.isAssignableFrom()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

From the javadoc:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `instanceof`, you need to know the class of "B" at compile time so if the elements contain the class name then you can use it else **NO**

Also to add to it that `instanceof` can only be used with reference types, not primitive types

Comment: One question: Is arrayA considered to be a reference type?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
Class cA=arrayA[c].getClass();
Class cB=arrayB[c].getClass();
if (cA.isAssignableFrom(cB) {
   .... your code Here
}
```

This way you will use the Reflection API to dynamically load the classes of the objects inside the array and verify whether the one in arrayA is an instance of the one in arrayB (either as a direct instance or as a subclass).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the corresponding elements to have exactly the same types then the following is sufficient.

```
    if (arrayA[c].getClass() == arrayB[c].getClass()) {}
```

(Note that `==` and `equals` are equivalent for `Class` objects.)

If subtypes are acceptable, use the `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)` method instead.  Note that this method is asymmetric:

> `c1.isAssignableFrom(c2)` does not imply that `c2.isAssignableFrom(c1)`

---

> Is it possible to use instanceof with two elements in two different arrays?

No.  The Java language does not allow it.

The `instanceof` operator tests an object against a type, and the right hand operand must be either a `TypeReference`; i.e. a type or a type variable.  It cannot be an ordinary variable or expression; they are *syntactically* invalid in that position.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Class#isInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (arrayB[c].getClass().isInstance(arrayA[c])){
    // do something
}
```